# What happens after Retrofit request is completed?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a strange issue that seems to be related to Retrofit.

Let's say that I have an sample app that has only one Activity. It also has `windowBackground` set to red color in the `styles.xml`.
Now I do something like this in `onCreate`:

```
public void onCreate() {
    retrofit.foo()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ response ->
            // ignore
        }, { error ->
            finish()
        })
}
```

To test it I'm running this app without internet connection, so it always calls `onError`.

I expect that after I launch the app, it will show red background, try to make a request, and then it will call `finish()` and Activity will be closed.
Functionally it seems to work ok but visually there is a weird issue. It shows red background, then it turns black for a moment and then red again and finally the app is closed.

I tried to replace Retrofit call with a simple observable that emits error after some delay and it worked correctly (no black background). That's why I think it's something related to Retrofit.
The behavior is the same if I do `onErrorResumeNext` and call `finish()` in `onNext`. But if I have internet connection and call succeeded then there is no black background. Seems like something is happening when non http error occurs.

After some investigation I've noticed that it's probably not OkHttp's fault. I wrapped OkHttp call in `Obsevable.create` and when it emitted an error I called `finish()`. No black screen in this case. Only when using Retrofit. I also tried using Retrofit without RxJava - simple `call.enqueue` and it's not working correctly (black screen is showing).

I'm using Retrofit 2.0.2 with RxJava adapter. And I've reproduced this issue on Android 5.1.1.

Comment: So the red background is set in the layout xml? Are you setting a black background on your own anywhere in the app? Is it possible that the black bg shows when you try to run too much in the main thread?

Comment: Background is set in App's theme using windowBackground attribute. Activity has no layout at all. Maybe you're right and there is too much work in the main thread but it's not my work. I have no other code than I've posted above.

Comment: Try to modify the `subscribe` parameters to do nothing and see if still happens. If it still happens, then it is the observable-observer synchronization mechanism freezing up the main thread.

Comment: If I do nothing then it shows red background, so it's a correct behavior. I've experimented a bit more and when I have an internet connection and call succeedes then it's behaving correctly. Only if some non-http exception occurs it shows this black background. Also when I call finish() after some delay (for example 100ms) then it works good.

Comment: I've decided to report an issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1918

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be having an issue with is activity animation. Try disabling activity animation with

```
public void onCreate() {
    retrofit.foo()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ response ->
            // ignore
        }, { error -> {
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        })
}
```